# JavaScript OR (||) Short Circuit Strange Behavior

Tags: javascript, variables, short-circuiting

I am writing a small function that takes in a parameter and attempts to call `parseInt(value) || value.toUpperCase()` but it is failing to work as expected with certain values.

```
function convert(value)
{
    return parseInt(value) || value.toUpperCase();
}
```

Some example outputs are
`convert("asdf") -> "ASDF"`
`convert("Car")  -> "CAR"`
`convert("1")    -> 1`
`convert("52")   -> 52`

But for some reason when I input "0" I am getting "0" back out.  I've attempted to call `parseInt("0")` and it is correctly parsing `0` out, but when coupled with the `|| "0".toUpperCase()` it is always returning the string `"0"`.

The only excuse I can come up with is that `0 || "0"` always resolved to `"0"` because it is treating `0` as undefined or null (which my understanding was that the [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of JavaScript was only short-circuited with `undefined`, `null`, or `false` values).


I hope someone could provide me a little bit of clarity regarding this issue.

Comment: The value `0` is falsy. The list of falsy values is `0`, `""`, `undefined`, `null`, and `NaN`. (That doesn't include `false`; it's a philosophical question whether it's "falsy" or not :)

Comment: Looks like you already answered the question yourself. Although `0` is not treated *as* `undefined`, rather *like* `undefined` and any other value that is falsy.

Comment: The values that would *prevent* the short-circuiting of the `||` are `0` `null` `undefined` `NaN` `""` `false`. Any other value would trigger the short-circuit and prevent the evaluation of the second operand.

Comment: More reading on Falsy values. http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Comment: Thanks @Adoba for a great link.  The article shared is very insightful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`0` is falsy, so the other expression in the logical `||` will be evaluated. That is why you are getting `"0"`. You can confirm that like this

```
1 || console.log("First");
0 || console.log("Second");
# Second
```

Since `1` is truthy, it short circuits and doesn't execute the `console.log("First")`, but `0` is falsy so it goes ahead and executes `console.log("Second")`

Comment: Thank you for the concise and accurate answer, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you actually want to do is this:

```
return isNaN(value) ? value.toUpperCase() : parseInt(value);
```

Explanation: this checks, whether `value` can be converted to a `Number` and then returns the appropriate conversion.

Comment: isNaN(parseInt(value)) can be isNaN(value)

Comment: Thanks for the revised function, this does exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Luke good find! Though there is a difference for corner cases like "15a" and depending on whether Aaronias wants to have these parsed as Number or uppercase String, he'd need the `parseInt()` or not. I assume that "15a" should be a String, so I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: If you're ever passing a non-string, keep in mind that `isNaN(null)` is `false` and `isNaN({})` is `true`. Both cases result in an error. If you're expecting any value `isNaN(value) ? String(value).toUpperCase() : Number(value);` will work better. Number uses the same rules as isNaN, which is different than parseInt, as S.B. points out.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated yourself, `0` is treated as false (it's falsy). Since it's false, the expression on the right is evaluated, and the uppercase version of `"0"` obviously is the same.

What exactly are you trying to do using `|| value.toUpperCase()` there?